# Select listener when using DBCA on Oracle RAC

Tags: oracle, listener, oracle-rac

I have a 2 node oracle cluster (RAC). I created a listener and a database.

I want to create another listener and create a new database on the same cluster using the secondary listener for the new database.

In a single node mode where I define more than one listener on machine, when I use DBCA to create the database, a "Select Listener" page appears for me and I can choose the listener.

I created a new listener with the grid user for cluster-wide use, but when I use DBCA to create a database, the listener selection page does not appear.

Can any help me to choose secondary listener for new database?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it doesn't make sense to have two databases on the same set of RAC servers. Do not confuse between the terminolgy between `database` or `database instances` with `logical schema(s)`. I have seen `SQL Server` developers confusing with schema and Oracle terminology of database.

Is it possible or not is a different scope altogether, but what you want to achieve is scalable and meaningful is my concern.

You could more explain about your requirement, what exactly makes you think to do so. I would be happy to guide you further. As of now, it doesn't make much sense.

**update** To Configure Multiple Listeners for Your Database Using DBCA, please read 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e48195/undrstnd.htm#BEIDJJAG

You said, you have already created two listeners, but they were not listed in dbca. Please check the `listener.ora` if it has both the entries. If not, then create a new unique entry in listener.ora. Try again with dbca.

Comment: I want 2 listener on one RAC database for training only not read environment.

Comment: Check the update in my answer. Can you check the `listerner.ora` file whether it has two unique entries.